# How to create a form object from 2 different model objects in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 2 objects, both from different Model classes, and want to show a form containing some fields from each one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

The way I do it is by creating two `ModelForm` classes that use the `fields` Meta attribute to specify which [subset of fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/?from=olddocs#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) to use to display in the form. I display both forms in the template, and handle them in the view.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Django Form/ModelForm objects do not equal HTML forms, they're just collections of fields; you wrap them in the <form> tag yourself.  Don't go into contortions squeezing everything into one Form/ModelForm, use as many as you need and put them all inside a single HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

Just create 2 separate forms, the problem with with the approach of the guy above is that you would lose .save().  Forms are really meant to represent 1 single set of data, the data for each of yours models is really a separate set of data.  This is why forms doesn't include the  tag when the render.

Answer (score -2):

I've never tried this but you could have two ModelForm classes defined in your code and then make a new plain `Form` class that in its `__init__` created a copy of each `ModelForm` and copied the fields into itself.

Something like:

```
class DualForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model1 = Model1Form(**kwargs)
        model2 = Model2Form(**kwargs)

        for f in model1.fields:
            self.fields[f] = model1.fields[f]

        for f in model2.fields:
            self.fields[f] = model2.fields[f]

class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    ... your model form...

class Model2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    ... your other model form...
```

I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Just make sure you pass data arguments through to the `ModelForms` and trap and bubble exceptions out... I'm also not sure what would happen if you have conflicting field names. That could be troublesome...

Comment: And these are exactly the kind of error-prone contortions people go to when they assume everything has to be squeezed into one Form object... just use two!